# How to use itemId in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a view defined as following:

```
    Ext.define('senchaTest.view.ModelDetailsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [
    ],
    xtype: 'modeldetailsview',

    config: {
        modelName: null
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            itemId: 'modelinformationview-name-label'
        }]
    },
    updateModelName: function(modelName) {
        var components = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.modelinformationview #modelinformationview-name-label');
        if (components && components.length > 0) {
            components[0].setHtml(modelName);
        };
    }
});
```

I want to reuse this view in a tab panel. I have two tabs in tab panel. Each will have an instance of the above defined view. However, each will have different data and role.
When I try to set the config values of instances of these views, only one config is used. I understand that this happens because Ext.ComponentQuery queries the same component (For example, '.modelinformationview #modelinformationview-name-label'). It returns two components from each instance of the created views, I pick the first one and use that. Hence only one view is used always.
I want to know how to reuse defined views like this. I have some idea that Controllers can play a role in achieving this. But I haven't yet figured the best way to do it. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is an instance of the right `modeldetailsview` in the `updateModelName()` function, hence it is as simple as:

```
updateModelName: function(modelName) {
    var component = this.down('[itemId=modelinformationview-name-label]');
    component.setHtml(modelName);
}
```

[EDIT]

I made this example to show you how to reuse components identifying them by `itemId`: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/45o.

I defined the `Fiddle.view.Main` with two instances of `Fiddle.view.Reusable`, then in the initialize event of the Main view I get a reference to Main view, and from it I use `Ext.Container.getComponent()` to get the instances of the components by `itemId`.

`itemId` is just a way of identifying an instance of a component without polluting the global `id` space, and you can use it both to get an item in a container with `Ext.Container.getComponent('foo');` like I did in my example, or more generally with  `componentQuery('[itemId=foo]');` like I did to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Anubis. I've marked your answer correct since it solves the problem. However, it'd be really helpful if somebody can explain how to reuse components using Controllers. Since a controller can have a single instance, how to handle multiple instances of the same view uniquely?

Comment: I will make a Fiddle to elaborate a bit on that as soon as I have time.

Comment: @VarunSingh edited my answer with an explanation on how to use `itemId` to identify instances of components.

Comment: Thanks Anubis for improving the answer. So as I understand while declaring the instances, I will have to give each instance a different itemId and go from there. Though this may result in a little code redundancy but I think this is the way to to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not redundancy, you just can't identify an instance without an identifier ;)

Answer (score 2):

A simple example :

```
Ext.define('App.view.Mygrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myGrid',

    itemId: 'myGrid',
}
```

Then later you can add this by adding it to the `items` property of a parent like this :

```
items:
[{ xtype: 'myGrid' }]
```

Note that you don't need the `itemId` in this case. The `alias` property makes it so that you can instantiate views using the `alias` as an `xtype`.

Comment: What's the point of setting an `itemId` when defining a class like you are doing? I don't get it.